# Prove that $\beta$ is a basis for $\tau \iff\forall x\in X,\forall U\in\tau,x\in U,\exists\beta_x\in\beta:x\in\beta_x\subset U$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space.

$\beta$ is a basis for $\tau \iff\forall x\in X,\forall U\in\tau,x\in U,\exists\beta_x\in\beta:x\in\beta_x\subset U$

I did this side $\implies$

Now for the other side, we want to show that $\forall U\in\tau,\exists\{\beta_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}\in\beta:U=\bigcup\beta_\alpha$, which is the definition of a basis.

Let $U\in\tau.$

We have that $\forall x\in X,x\in U,\exists\beta_x\in\beta:x\in\beta_x\subset U$

I was thinking about taking the union of this contention $x\in\beta_x\subset U$ to have something similar to $U=\bigcup\beta_\alpha$, but a problem will appear since I want the equality and not this $\subset.$

How to continue the proof?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $\beta_x$ contains $x,$ the union of all the $\beta_x$'s will contain all the $x$'s, that is, the union will contain all points of $U.$

Comment: @bof Therefore $U=\bigcup\beta_\alpha$. Will the proof be formal if I write it exactly as you wrote? Or do I need to improve something?

Comment: If I had to hand this in as homework, I' d start by saying "For each $x\in U$ choose $\beta_x\in\beta$ such that . . .. " Then I would prove that $\bigcup_{x\in U}\beta_x\subseteq U$ and that $U\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in U}\beta_x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U \in \tau$. 
By the right hand side, for each $x \in U$ we pick $\beta_x \in \beta$ such that $x \in \beta_x \subseteq U$.

Then indeed $U = \cup \{\beta_x: x \in U\}$.

If $y \in \cup \{\beta_x: x \in U\}$, then $y \in \beta_x$ (for some $x \in U$) and as $\beta_x \subseteq U$, we have $y \in U$. (Or, because all $\beta_x \subseteq U$, so is their union.)

If $y \in U$, then $y \in \beta_y \subseteq \cup \{\beta_x: x \in U\}$ (as $\beta_y$ is just one of the sets in the union). (Every $x \in U$ is in its "own" $\beta_x$, so in the union.)